# GUI for linux c

Tags: c, linux, user-interface

is it possible to develop a GUI in linux c??
how can be do that??

Comment: Not the answer, but some unseeked advice, as you have not specified why you want to develop in "linux c": I'd rather keep the GUI platform independent (so that it runs on Linux, Windows, Mac etc) using one of the "platform-independent" libraries like Qt, wxWidgets etc. and prefer to use Java or some other language for GUI (because it is simpler to use them) if speed or some other constraint does not force me to use C++ or C.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to develop GUI applications for Linux with pure C you can use [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/).  IF C++ is an option you also have [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/).

Comment: Motif is fine but I wouldn't call it a modern option.  But yes it can do GUIs.  You can also include wxWidgets.

Answer (score 2):

There are many graphical toolkits for linux such as [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/), [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products), [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/), and [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/). They have bindings for many languages such as C and Python. I suggest you google around to see what you like. If you want a RAD you may want to check out things like [glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) and [qt creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools).

Comment: From what I understand, there is no C binding for QT.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728509/does-qt-have-a-c-interface

Answer (score 2):

XForms is a graphical user interface toolkit for X based on the X11 Xlib library. I.e., it allows you to create windows, containing all kinds of widgets (buttons, sliders, browsers, menus etc.) with a few lines of code and then attach actions to the widgets, i.e., have some function called when a button is pressed. To make this even easier XForms comes with a program called fdesign that allows you to design a GUI for a program directly on the screen and which then writes out the necessary C code for it.

XForms is written in C and has a C API, i.e., you can use it directly from a C program. It should work with X11 R4, R5, R6 & R7 and under all kinds of operating systems of the UNIX family (including MacOS X) as well as at least OpenVMS, OS/2 und Windows NT 4.0. In addition, the library is extensible and new objects can easily be created and added to the library.

http://xforms-toolkit.org

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use a GUI toolkit such as [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) that uses C, or find a wrapper for one of the various C++ toolkits.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/). It may be difficult to write complex interface with it. But FLTK, as its name implies, is very small and fairly fast. What is more important, it is cross-platform, working nicely on the three major OS: linux, windows and mac. In my view, GTK/Qt/wxWidgets are far too heavy. If you statically link to these library, you will end up with a huge executable which eat up the memory; if you dynamically link to them, users have to install the library before hand, which is always troublesome.

EDIT: I just realize that this is a "C" question. Then the best choice should be GTK. If you need graphics but not interface/widgets (e.g. menu, scrollbar and so on), opengl is also nice.