# Qt creator pure C project

Tags: c, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I am trying to use the Qt Creator for Ansi C program development. My problem is that I am still getting typical for g++ warnings, such as `variable length array used`. Is there a way to force the Qt Creator to use gcc only and never g++ at any stage (compile, link etc)?

Comment: Isn't Qt a C++ library?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1728509/1606345

Answer (score 1):

I've needed to think about this twice in the past, when building Qt/C++ projects that were using a subproject that I wanted to compile as a C static library in QtCreator:  [FluidSynth](https://sourceforge.net/p/vmpk/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/mobile/fluidsynth/fluidsynth.pro) and [Sonivox](https://github.com/pedrolcl/Linux-SonivoxEas/blob/master/sonivox/sonivox.pro).

QtCreator has a wizard to create a plain C application (Welcome -> New Project -> Non-Qt Project -> Plain C Application:

[image: QtCreator Plain C Application Wizard]

The compiler is not a problem; qmake does the right thing based on the suffix of the source files: gcc for *.c, and g++ for *.cpp . You only need to worry about linking, and about LFLAGS and CFLAGS when they need particular values:

```
QMAKE_LINK = $$QMAKE_LINK_C
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH = ...
QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG = ...
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE = ...
```