# Undefined reference when I'm linking C files in C++ inside Qt framework

Tags: c++, c, qt, qt5

**Introduction:**

I have a C++ project inside the [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29) framework, and I have recently created a [CAN-bus SAE J1939 library](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Open-SAE-J1939) in pure 100% [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) code. The library works very well. I will now import the library into my Qt project in [Qt Creator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator).

*Note*:  The compiler is [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) 5.15.2

**Method:**

I have included *.h* files in C++ with Qt framework by including the line inside my *.pro* project file.

```
include(ThirdLibrary/OpenSAEJ1939/OpenSAEJ1939.pri)
```

Inside the `OpenSAEJ1939.pri` file, it is written

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
```

Here is my project folder:

[image]

The path `ThirdLibrary/OpenSAEJ1939/Open_SAE_J1939/`

[image]

So when I created a C++ source file and then added the C source function, I got *undefined reference to Open_SAE_J1939_Listen_For_Messages*.

```
#include "Can_Bus_Listen_Thread.h"

CAN_Bus_Listen_Thread::CAN_Bus_Listen_Thread(J1939* j1939, bool* usbMessageAvailable, bool* startCANBusListenThread){
    this->j1939 = j1939;
    this->usbMessageAvailable = usbMessageAvailable;
    this->startCANBusListenThread = startCANBusListenThread;
}

void CAN_Bus_Listen_Thread::run(){
    while(1){
        if(*this->startCANBusListenThread && *this->usbMessageAvailable)
            Open_SAE_J1939_Listen_For_Messages(this->j1939);
        msleep(1);
    }
}
```

I look inside the C++ header *Can_Bus_Listen_Thread.h* and I can see that I have imported the C header file from *ThirdLibrary/OpenSAEJ1939/Open_SAE_J1939/*.

```
#ifndef CAN_BUS_LISTEN_THREAD_H
#define CAN_BUS_LISTEN_THREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QtSerialPort>
#include "ThirdLibrary/OpenSAEJ1939/Open_SAE_J1939/Open_SAE_J1939.h"

class CAN_Bus_Listen_Thread : public QThread {
public:
    CAN_Bus_Listen_Thread(J1939* j1939, bool* usbMessageAvailable, bool* startCANBusListenThread);
private:
    J1939* j1939;
    bool* startCANBusListenThread;
    bool* usbMessageAvailable;
    void run();
};

#endif // CAN_BUS_LISTEN_THREAD_H
```

I have successfully included the `C` header files, but these header files cannot find the `C` source files. And yes, the `Open_SAE_J1939_Listen_For_Messages` is surrounded with `extern "C" { }` here inside [Open_SAE_J1939.h](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Open-SAE-J1939/blob/main/Src/Open_SAE_J1939/Open_SAE_J1939.h).

Have I forgot something? C++ should be able to read C source files if they are surrounded with `extern "C" { }`

```
#ifndef OPEN_SAE_J1939_OPEN_SAE_J1939_H_
#define OPEN_SAE_J1939_OPEN_SAE_J1939_H_

/* Layers */
#include "../Open_SAE_J1939/Structs.h"
#include "../SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-71_Application_Layer/Application_Layer.h"
#include "../SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-73_Diagnostics_Layer/Diagnostics_Layer.h"
#include "../SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-81_Network_Management_Layer/Network_Management_Layer.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* This functions must be called all the time, or be placed inside an interrupt listener */
void Open_SAE_J1939_Listen_For_Messages(J1939 *j1939);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* OPEN_SAE_J1939_OPEN_SAE_J1939_H_ */
```

Comment: Have you added the library to the compile command? This error doesn't seem as if something wasn't included, but rather that the library defining that something is not linked. An other worrying thing is that it seems that you work with windows, but `__declspec(dllimport)` is not used. In that case the sources should be compiled as well and linked against/ static library should be used

Comment: @Lala5th Thank you for your reply. `Have you added the library to the compile command?` -> No, I don't know how to do that.  `An other worrying thing is that it seems that you work with windows` -> Yes, Windows is horror. It's always something it complains about.  `sources should be compiled as well and linked against/ static library should be used` -> Yes, but the QT IDE gives me errors about "undefined reference" to C-files that are surrounded with `Extern "C"`

Comment: I may have missed it here, but I do not see what compiler you are using.  Regardless, there will be compiler specific documentation on how to link a library, you can learn how there.  If you are using gcc, an [example is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6016851/645128)

Comment: This might help if `OpenSAEJ1939` is a compiled library https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718447/adding-external-library-into-qt-creator-project, otherwise you should add the sources to be compiled as well. As to the error, it seems that the IDE recognises linker errors as well and that it isn't triggered by the lack of declaration in a header file, but rather by the lack of libraries defining the function.

Comment: @ryyker I'm using MinGW 5.15.2 compiler.

Comment: MinGW includes a port of the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC), so yes, you are using gcc.  (I placed that information in your post.) Did you look at/try what the link said?

Comment: @ryyker I haven't done that. I will try. Where should I add the linker `-l` in QT?

Comment: @ryyker Sorry. I'm using QT 5.15.2 and MinGW 64-bit 8.1.

Comment: _"Where should I add the linker -l in QT?"_...  You don't.  `-l` is a compiler switch to link a library during the build.  It will be part of the compiler command if you are using command line.  If you are using an IDE, such as Code::Blocks, or Eclipse, then read the documentation to include the library under compiler/linking methods for that environment.

Comment: @ryyker So you think that's the issue for me, I haven't link the source `C` files?

Comment: @ryyker I'm using QT Creator

Comment: It is not perfectly clear what the issue is.  There may be more than one.  The message:  _"undefined reference to `Open_SAE_J1939_Listen_For_Messages`"_ could be a missing source file, or library.  I only focused on library as follow-up on previous comments.

Comment: _"I'm using QT Creator "_.  Then you need to become familiar with how to set up that environment.  That can only be done through spending time in the documentation, [this section for example.](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-tool-chains.html)

Comment: @ryyker The source file is not missing. I can see it inside the folders.

Comment: @ryyker I have successfully imported all .c and .h files now and the IDE does not warns me about undefined reference. But...some of the .h files can the IDE not find. I don't know why.

Comment: `#include "../../ISO_11783/ISO_11783_Enums/Enum_Auxiliary_And_General_Purpose_Valves.h"` no such file or dictionary. Can this be a classical compiler issue, that the name is too long?

Comment: @ryyker No issue there. I just right click on my project -> Import new folder and then I selected my ThirdLibrary folder. Bam...all files included. I have been told by QT experts to import files on the method I did above. Told them it did not work "It has to work!" they said.

Comment: Does QT have the [ability to interface with C libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729205/645128)?

Comment: @ryyker I think I got it....It seems that the issue is not QT, instead its `"../../` that causing problems.

Comment: @ryyker Also I removed the `.pri` file because it's useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

1. right-click on your project in Qt.
2. Select "Add existing dictionary"
3. Mark the dictionary you want to import. Now you are seeing lots of `.c` and `.h` files inside the `.pro` file.

Hint: Don't use `../../`. That can cause troubles. Instead, use the project path instead, e.g.,

```
"ThirdLibrary/OpenSAEJ1939/...your_h_files.h"
```

You don't need the `.pri` file. Get rid of it.