# Can I write apps for KDE Plasma (preferably using Qt? with C?

Tags: c++, c, qt, project, kde-plasma

I recently finished learning the basics of C and I want to take my learning to the next level. I am not sure what projects a noob like me can build but making apps for KDE Plasma sounds like a cool idea since I mainly use KDE Neon. The problem is, I've been told that in order to write apps with Qt, you need to use C++ and I can't use C++ since my Uni requires me to learn C.

So the question is, can I write apps for KDE Plasma using C? And if not, what else can I make with C as a noob?

Comment: I expect the answer is no and I think this is related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728509/does-qt-have-a-c-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728509/does-qt-have-a-c-interface)

Comment: Has your university forbidden you from learning C++? If not then you can learn it on your own. Actually I think it is very useful to learn C and C++ alongside.

Comment: @V.K. : The problem is that for learners, the languages look too similar, while in reality they're far apart. C++ and C diverged about 3 decades ago.

Comment: Yes, I know. But it is easy to learn the differences. And in my opinion Qt API is very user friendly. It abstracts you from all the hardcore C++ stuff. You only need to learn OOP (which is a must for any programmer anyway), basic template usage (to be able to write `QVector<int>` and a bit of namespaces. And that's all.

Comment: @V.K. no my university hasn't forbidden me from learning C++ but learning it is pointless since all of the projects I can submit need to be in C otherwise they won't even consider them.